# How to use object.find on nested Value

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing

i have an object in grovvy with a list of key:value pairs. I'm using this code to extract only the matrix value for this Object.

Object :

```
[{"id":null,"dimension":"f7f04751-5ac9-4867-a742-6f69a53d99d3","matrix_value":"ac726cd4-0aaf-4b4b-91c1-bceda8dded04","name":"Linear","include":false,"children":[{"id":null,"dimension":"f7f04751-5ac9-4867-a742-6f69a53d99d3","matrix_value":"efc05bdb-ebc8-4167-85fb-9e5a63a1200b","name":"Little Linear","include":false,"children":[]}]},{"id":null,"dimension":"f7f04751-5ac9-4867-a742-6f69a53d99d3","matrix_value":"a2b932d3-14f0-480f-8eeb-d1fc00a1c7ab","name":"Not Linear","include":false,"children":[]}]
```

I know that with it.name i search only at the top level values of the object. How can i  modify this code to check if the field children is not null and in that case apply the find also to the child element and extract the matrix_valiue? Thank you.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;


def Dimensions = vars.getObject("Dimensions")



String[] DimensionKeyset = vars.getObject("DimensionKeySet");
String Dimension_name = DimensionKeyset[Integer.parseInt(vars.get("ContoDimensions"))]
String[] Values = Dimensions.get(Dimension_name)
def Body = vars.get("Body_Get")
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def list = jsonSlurper.parseText(Body);
def rc_dimension_values = []
log.info("La lista è: "+ list.toString())

log.info("La vera lista è: "+ list.getClass())


for(v : Values) {
    
    rc_dimension_values += list.find { it.name.trim() == v.trim() }.matrix_value
     log.info("L'oggetto è:" + list.find { it.name.trim() == v.trim() } )
    log.info("Check For Values: " + v)

    
    
}

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(rc_dimension_values)

vars.put("rc_dimension_values", builder.toString());
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: i want to extract a json object with ["matrix_value_1", "matrix_value_2"]

Comment: what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get all `matrix_value` wherever they are the easiest would be switching to [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor). If you use deep scan operator like:

```
$..matrix_value
```

it will store all the values to the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

[image]

---

If you want to stay with Groovy you can use the following code snippet which uses the same [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library which is under the hood of the JSON Extractor:

```
vars.put('rc_dimension_values',new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),'$..matrix_value')).toPrettyString())
```

it will generate a JSON Array from the found `matrix_value` attributes and store it into `rc_dimension_values` variable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, but i want to get only the matrix_value of the element  with the same name field present in a CSV file. Thats why i used that equivalence in the code.

Comment: So i Want to extract all matrix_values of the element  for example having name = Linear and also its eventual children matrix_values (there are cases where the children field is empty).

Comment: Then you need the combination of filter and deep scan operators: `$..[?(@.name == 'Linear')]..matrix_value`.  If you want to use a variable go for [**vars** shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) like `vars.put('rc_dimension_values',new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),'$..[?(@.name == \'' + vars.get('variableFromCSV') + '\')]..matrix_value')).toPrettyString())`

Comment: The problem is that i inserted this code in a for loop that iterates  on values  and this request is inserted in a loop that iterates through csv rows. but it extract the values only for the last csv row while the response is present also in the previous loops. How i can fix this? Thank you   `for(v : Values) {

 
 rc_dimension_values += com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),'$..[?(@.name == \'' + v + '\')]..matrix_value')
}`

Comment: I managed to make it work adding v.trim(), Thank you